# Custom icon in dropdown react

Tags: reactjs, svg, icons

I have my svg file and I want to render my icon in React Dropdown Component. The DropdownItem component receives some props but I'm not able to render my icon. The code is something similar:

```
const myIcon = {
  id: 'iconId',
  hint: 'hint',
  icon: {
    svg: filePath
  }
}
```

And then

```
<Dropdown.Item
   icon={item.icon}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
   onClick={item.onClick}
   >
```

Any ideas on how to do?